# 3d polyline in WPF

Tags: wpf, graphics, 3d

I've got a geometry described in a file in term of faces. Faces are not real meshes, but polylines laying in a certain 3d plane. How can I render this kind of object in WPF ? I guess i have to triangulate, but which algoritm should be used ?

Answer (score 1):

Although pretty old [this](http://3dtools.codeplex.com/) might help you, have a look at the ScreenSpaceLines3D.

Comment: thanks Erno,it is really interesting: this allow me to draw the "contour" of my faces in 3d, but what if I want to fill these faces ? I suppose I have to triangulate them, but not sure.

Comment: Yes, you will always have to triangulate them because triangles are the only primitives know (natively) by WPF. Have a look at this book to learn more about WPF and 3D: http://www.charlespetzold.com/3D/

Comment: Also if the polylines are in a single plane you could also project the lines into 2D space and use a canvas and a PolyLine without ever going to 3D and triangulation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747354.aspx

Comment: @Erno are you sure in the Petzold tehre is something about triangulations ?

Comment: Not about triangulation but the book contains a neat method to create 3D Primitives. I would leave triangulation to another program (if possible) but in WPF you would have to write it yourself (or copy/use someones' code)

Comment: @Erno yeap, I'm looking for something already done implementation, pseudo code as well, but with "industrial strength"